# Laravel save a input with extra value data

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i am trying to save a input value from a time data:

```
<input type='text' name="starttime"/>
```

On mi example i am saving the data 3:30 for a calendar form, but to use on the calendar i need save with a "T" before the value like "T3:30"

on mi controller i save the data on the form like this:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
     'titulo' => 'required|max:255',
     'start' => 'required|max:255',
     'starttime' => 'required|max:255',  <---- 
     'end' => 'required|max:255',
     'endtime' => 'required|max:255',    <----
     'descripcion' => 'required|max:255',
     'color' => 'required|max:255',
 ]);
 $Calendarios=Calendarios::create($validatedData);
```

what could I do to save the information as I need?

Comment: cant you just concatenate the T onto the time before calling the calendar? Or you can just concatenate when saving into the db `$time = "T".$time;`

Comment: its time format you can't save string in time column you need to save it as string

Comment: Parker Dell, thx! is a great advice! im doing the concatenation way. sid Heart just swiched to the right value :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new array after validation and then just add the 'T' to the `starttime` of the new array. Like so:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'titulo' => 'required|max:255',
    'start' => 'required|max:255',
    'starttime' => 'required|max:255',
    'end' => 'required|max:255',
    'endtime' => 'required|max:255',
    'descripcion' => 'required|max:255',
    'color' => 'required|max:255', ]);
]);

$newValidatedData = $this->validateRequest();

$newValidatedData['starttime'] = 'T' . $this->validateRequest()['starttime'];

$calendarios = Calendarios::create($newValidatedData);
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: to be honest im trying to uderstand it but im no sure how this method work, my function call public function setStarttimeAttribute(Request $request) then i cast the $validationData and at the end $Calendar=Calendar::create($validatedData); im new in the interaction with laravel so i should use $request->attributes['starttime'] = 'T' . $value;?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a [Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) within the `Calanderios` Model.

```
class Calanderios extends Model {

    // ...

    public function setStarttimeAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['starttime'] = 'T' . $value;
    }

}
```

Comment: @clausvargas If it is necessary to add 'T' every time, this is probably a better answer than mine. However, don't forget to ignore the mutator later if you want to use its value for something else than the calendar.

Comment: to be honest im trying to uderstand it but im no sure how this method work, my function call *public function setStarttimeAttribute(Request $request)* then i cast the *$validationData* and at the end *$Calendar=Calendar::create($validatedData);* im new in the interaction with laravel so i should use *$request->attributes['starttime'] = 'T' . $value;*?

Answer (score 0):

first i thanx you so much  Lucas Arbex, Parker Dell, sid heart, Lucas Arbex, Brandon Bronisz.

i found the answer as the nex way:

public function CalendariosStore(Request $request)
    {

```
$starttime = $request->input('T'.'starttime'); //<-- here i cast the input startttime with the dot 'T'

$endtime = $request->input('T'.'endtime'); //<-- here i cast the input endtime with the dot 'T'

$validatedData = $request->validate([
     'titulo' => 'required|max:255',
     'start' => 'required|max:255',
     //'starttime' => 'required|max:255',
     'end' => 'required|max:255',
     //'endtime' => 'required|max:255',
     'descripcion' => 'required|max:255',
     'color' => 'required|max:255',
 ]);
```

//here i insert on my table the validation and the time with the T with the date start and end value
     $Calendarios=Calendarios::create($validatedData, $starttime, $endtime);

```
 return redirect('calendarios')->with('success','Great work! Naw you team can start working.');
}
```

source: https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests
and you awesome help guys  ty

Answer (score 0):

another answer i found late was swich the validation for a create and direct send the insert:

```
public function CalendariosStore(Request $request)
{

    $Calendarios=Calendarios::create([
        'titulo'      => $request->input('titulo'),
        'start'       => $request->input('start'),
        'starttime'   => 'T'.$request->input('starttime'),   <-----
        'end'         => $request->input('end'),
        'endtime'     => 'T'.$request->input('endtime'),     <-----
        'descripcion' => $request->input('descripcion'),
        'color'       => $request->input('color'),
    ]);
return redirect('calendarios')->with('success','Great work! Naw you team can start working.');

 }
```

and made a "short" validation :

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
                'titulo'               => 'required|max:255',
                'start'                => 'required|max:255',
                'starttime'            => 'required|max:255',
                'end'                  => 'required|max:255',
                'endtime'              => 'max:255',
                'descripcion'          => 'max:255',
                'color'                => 'max:255',
            ]);
```

hope it can help someon else , and thx again